# utf-8 encode url parameters for resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, resttemplate, diacritics

I'm using spring `RestTemplate.exchange(URI)`.

The uri was assembled with UriComponentsBuilder.
one of my query params was 
`query=München`

If I take the url generated from the logs, and use it with curl, it works.
When I let rest template run the query, it does not.

Something about the umlaut not getting encoded?

How do I get UriCompenentsBuilder and/or RestTemplate to cope with the umlaut?

I know I can use a string url with RestTemplate that looks like this:

`query=M%C3%BCnchen`

and that works.

Comment: When I log `UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand("München").toUri()` I see `München` in the log output but when I call `RestTemplate.exchange()`, servers receives `GET /resource?query=M%C3%BCnchen HTTP/1.1`. Are you sure server does not receive `query=M%C3%BCnchen`?

Comment: It is because I use Apache  `HttpClient`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when `RestTemplate` is initialized with Spring default request factory (`SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory`) , e.g.:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
```

Replace default request factory with `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and Apache `HttpClient`:

```
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
```

Then call `restTemplate.exchange()` as you would normally.